# How to match Schema of two Data Frames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have default column names saved in a table and I want to match the column name saved in a table with column names I will be receiving in CSV file.

Result of below Code is:

if the file has the same column names as stored in the table to match then do some processing else exit and throw an email of mismatch schema.

Here is my code:

```
val expectedschemadf = spark.sql(s"""SELECT columnname FROM  table""").columns
val receivedschemadf = spark.table(vendorfile.toString).columns

if(expectedschemadf.size == receivedschemadf.size)
{
  breakable {for(i<-0 to expectedschemadf.size-1 by 1)
  {
    if (!(receivedschemadf contains expectedschemadf(i)))
    {
      print("fail")
      break
    }

  }
  }
}
else(print("fail"))
```

Result i want:

i want to automate the above for loop into some predefined function or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i done my task.

```
val expectedCol = dfMetaDataFileTracker.select("COLUMNNAME").collect().map(_.getString(0)).sorted.toList.map(_.toUpperCase()) 
val receivedCol = dfVendorFile.columns.sorted.toList.map(_.toUpperCase())
  if ((expectedCol.length == receivedCol.length) && (expectedCol.equals(receivedCol))) 
  {
    println("file schema matched with the expected schema!")
    break
  }
  else {
    println("file schema does not matched with the expected schema!")
    break        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code to check the two data frame schema

```
scala> val df1 = Seq((1,"a", 1.5)).toDF
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: double (nullable = false)

scala> val df2 = Seq((100,"x", 1231)).toDF
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: integer (nullable = false)


scala> df1.schema == df2.schema
res7: Boolean = false

scala> val df3 = Seq((100,"x", 123.1)).toDF
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df3.printSchema
root
 |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: double (nullable = false)


scala> df1.schema == df3.schema
res9: Boolean = true
```

Comment: rjshkrmara: 
Thank you for sharing your help. basically i have done the schema check part as you mentioned but now i want to compare the column names not the data types.

Comment: like: 
i have stored the column names in a table in hive and then need to compare those names with the header of file. if the header of file contains the same name of column as stored in table then continue, else break the job.

Comment: just get the dtypes of your input file once it is in DF.  if you take the first varient of the tupple it should give you list of your column names and second should have the Type.  you can get your table entires in to another seq and match the sequences

Answer (score 0):

I have not run this code in an environment but this is generally how one can get the names of columns into seq and Seq.equals should return true, if the order and members of the sequences are same and false if there are any differences.

```
val tableSeq = Seq("name","address","zip") // simulating a seq that you can retrive from your table 
val inputdf = spark.read.json("path") // reading some external data into dataframe
val columnListUnzipped = inputdf.dtypes.unzip // unzip will give tupple of column name and type
val columnList= columnListUnzipped._1 // get all column names as a seq
val isEqual= tableSeq.euqals(columnList) // compare 2 sequences with using equal as provided by Scala
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron: i have updated my question and i want to automate my code

Comment: not sure what else you need.. the above code should do what you want to accomplish